# Warning from TensorFlow environment

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.7, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN program, and it run successfully but I got some warning like this

[image: Warning message from TensorFlow]

and it also keep showing the warning similiar like that, is that any wrong with my environment? I'm using Tensorflow 1.15.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing wrong with your environment.

These are pure warnings of deprecation, you will not receive them once you update your tensorflow version to >=2.0.0.

Comment: should i update the TensorFlow to 2.0 or just leave it with 1.15 ?

Comment: Depending on the project that you are working on. If you have exact requirements that need 1.15, you should not. Otherwise, you can update to 2.1 or 2.2 which at the moment is the latest version. Since my comment answers your question, I will kindly ask you to accept and upvote it. Thank you.

Comment: If you have any more question we can create a separate chat in which I can explain more things to you.

Comment: oh oke, so how to create the chat room? I'm new in using stackoverflow